# text file to XML?

Tags: php, xml

Good Morning Everyone!

I am in the process of working on a PHP script that will allow a user to select a text file which follows the format below and convert it into an xml file.

**Text File**

```
Barcode:                           9091
Update Bib Status:                 Unable to update bib record: item barcode not found.
Update Holding Status:             Unable to update holdings record: item barcode not found.
Update Item Status:                Unable to update item record: item barcode not found.

Item ID:                           int
Barcode:                           int
Title:                             some stuff
Enum/Chron:                        
Call Number:                       alphanumeric stuff
Call Number Prefix:                
Holding Location:                  some stuff
Permanent Location:                some stuff
Temporary Location:                some stuff
Permanent Type:                    some stuff
Temporary Type:                    
Media Type:                        
Item Status:                       Not Charged
Statistical Categories:            
Magnetic Media:                    No
Sensitize:                         Yes
```

I would like to take the information in the left column and use them as XML elements and the items on the right column as content. Soo....the out put I would like to achive after the script is run would be an xml file like this:

```
<item>
<barcode>9091</barcode>
<ItemID>1234</ItemID>
<title>In the heart of the Sea</title>
....
</item>
```

I am able to get the file to upload, however I am stuck at creating the desired elements.

What I have so far is below:

**Current PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["scans"]["name"]); //retain file after upload
    $uploadOk=1;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["scans"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    echo "Your file has been successfully uploaded.<br>";//let user know file has been received.
    $data=file_get_contents($target_file); //open uploaded file...
    for ($i=0; $i<$data; i++){
        list($k, $v) = explode(":", $data); //split list into key value pairs
    }
    $xml= new XMLWriter("<holding></holding>");//start new xml
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please share your code where you have tried to convert txt to xml.

Comment: Sorry about that..I hit submit prematurely. Went back and edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic loop will look something like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

foreach (exploe("\n", $data) as $row ) 
{

    $rowData = explode(":", $row);
    $xml->addChild(trim($rowData[0]), trim($rowData[1]));

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $xml->asXML() );
echo "</pre>";
```

This splits your text file at each line break, and then uses whatever is left of the first colon in each row as the node name, and whatever is right of the first colon in each row as the node value (or, more precisely, whatever is between the first colon and a second colon, if it exists in the same row; you'll need to handle those yourself).  I added a trim in there to kill your whitespace, too.